# Slide and Rotate UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

I am trying to slide in a UIView while also rotating it.  The end result is basically a UIView that zips across the screen rotating about 70 degrees to the left, hits the edge, rotates about 50 degrees to the right, and finally ends up being still (after a few more wobbles).  I am able to get it sliding and rotating, but when I try to animate the second rotation (once it hits the edge), the frame goes back to the original value (back to the left of the screen).  How do I get the frame to stick once the UIView has slid across?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.4 delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGAffineTransform slideAndRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(300, 0);
                     slideAndRotate = CGAffineTransformRotate(slideAndRotate, RADIANS(75));

                     self.ticketImageView.transform = slideAndRotate;                 
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // set the frame to the location where it ended up
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.ticketImageView.frame));
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.35 
                          delay:0.05 
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
     | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         CGAffineTransform rightAngle1 = 
                         CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(-45.0));
                         [[self ticketImageView] setTransform:rightAngle1];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first animation block, you are creating transform that includes both a translation and a rotation.  In your second animation block, you are creating a transform that includes a rotation but not a translation.  So your view is no longer translated when you animate to the second transform.

I see that you have used the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option.  You might think this option makes the second transform stack with the first, but it doesn't.  The second transform replaces the first, regardless of the option.

A `UIView` has two properties that affect its location.  One is `transform`, which you are using.  The other is `center`.

Usually we use the `center` property to move a view around, and only use the `transform` property to rotate and scale the view.  I recommend you do the same.

Since you say you want the view to wobble a few more times, I suggest you try something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        self.ticketImageView.center = CGPointMake(180, self.ticketImageView.center.y);
    }];

    [self wobbleWithAmount:0.4 direction:1];
}

- (void)wobbleWithAmount:(CGFloat)amount direction:(CGFloat)direction {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:amount animations:^{
        self.ticketImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(amount * direction * M_PI * 0.5f);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (amount > 0.05f) {
            [self wobbleWithAmount:amount * 0.5f direction:-direction];
        } else {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:amount * 0.5f animations:^{
                self.ticketImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great tips!  It's definitely much easier using center than trying to translate the coordinates!  This algorithm works great.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the second transform `rightAngle1`, you should be using `[[self ticketImageView] transform]` instead of `CGAffineTransformIdentity`. Using the identity transform, you basically erase the first transform and start from scratch.